# Oracle: Invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, sql-merge

I am using the following query in oracle. However, it gives an error saying that "c.par" in line 5 is an invalid parameter. No idea why. The columns exist. I checked. I have been struggling with this for a long time. All I want to do is to merge one table into another and update it using oracle. Could someone please help?

```
MERGE INTO SPRENTHIERARCHIES 
USING ( SELECT c.PARENTCATEGORYID AS par,  
             e.rootcategoryId AS root 
        FROM  SPRENTCATEGORIES c,SPRENTHIERARCHIES e 
        WHERE e.root (+)= c.par 
      ) SPRENTCATEGORIES  
ON (SPRENTHIERARCHIES.rootcategoryId = SPRENTCATEGORIES.parentcategoryId) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET e.root=c.par
```

Comment: Your query doesn't really make sense.  Why are you using `merge` and not a simple `update`?

Comment: So the error is "invalid identifier" or "invalid parameter"? In either cases, doesn't it have an associated ORA- code?

Comment: Unless your SPRENTHIERARCHIES table has both `rootcategoryId` and `root` columns, and your SPRENTCATEGORIES  table has both `parentCategoryId` and `par` columns, then you checked that the wrong names existed. Maybe add the table definitions to the question to clarify. But this doesn't seem to really do anything, you would update to the same value when there is a match, if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e` and `c` aliases only exist within the query in the `using` clause. You're trying to refer to them in the `update` clause. You're also using a column alias from the `using` clause against the target table, which doesn't have that column (unless your tables have both rootcategoryId and root, and parentCategoryId and par).

So this:

```
UPDATE SET e.root=c.par
```

should be:

```
UPDATE SET SPRENTHIERARCHIES.rootcategoryId= SPRENTCATEGORIES.par
```

And in that `using` clause you're trying to use column aliases as the same level of query, so this:

```
    WHERE e.root (+)= c.par
```

should be:

```
    WHERE e.rootcategoryId (+)= c.PARENTCATEGORYID
```

Your `on` clause is wrong too, as that is *not* using the column alias:

```
ON (SPRENTHIERARCHIES.rootcategoryId = SPRENTCATEGORIES.par)
```

But I'd suggest you replace the old syntax in the `using` clause with proper join clauses:

```
MERGE INTO SPRENTHIERARCHIES 
USING ( SELECT c.PARENTCATEGORYID AS par,  
             e.rootcategoryId AS root 
        FROM  SPRENTCATEGORIES c
        LEFT JOIN SPRENTHIERARCHIES e 
        ON e.rootcategoryId = c.PARENTCATEGORYID 
      ) SPRENTCATEGORIES  
ON (SPRENTHIERARCHIES.rootcategoryId = SPRENTCATEGORIES.par) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET SPRENTHIERARCHIES.rootcategoryId= SPRENTCATEGORIES.par
```

You have a more fundamental problem though, as you're trying to update a joining column; this will get:

```
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated
```

As Gordon Linoff suggested you can use an update rather than a merge. Something like:

```
UPDATE SPRENTHIERARCHIES h
SET h.rootcategoryId = (
  SELECT c.PARENTCATEGORYID
  FROM SPRENTCATEGORIES c
  WHERE c.PARENTCATEGORYID = h.rootCategoryID
)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT null
  FROM SPRENTCATEGORIES c
  WHERE c.PARENTCATEGORYID = h.rootCategoryID
)
```

The `where exists` clause is there in case there not be a matching record - which the outer join in your original query implies. But in this form it's even more obvious that you're going to update `rootcategoryId` to the same value, since you're selecting the parentCategoryID *which is equal to it*. So the update (or merge) seems to be pointless.

Comment: I will be merging some more columns from SPRENTCATEGORIES in SPRENTHIERARCHIES and that's why I'm using merge.  Yes, I'm using 'c' and 'e' because otherwise it gives me the "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated" error.

Comment: @KavitaSalvi - you can't use merge if you're changing the column in the on clause, whatever name or alias you use. Changing it to make it even less valid won't help. If you're actually only updating other columns - since the update is currently pointless anyway - then you'll be OK. You can update multiple columns with an update statement too though.

Comment: Okay .. All I want to have is my SPRENTHIERARCHIES table updates, with some columns from SPRENTCATEGORIES , using  c.PARENTCATEGORYID = h.rootCategoryID. How should I do this in oracle?

Comment: Just don't `SET SPRENTHIERARCHIES.rootcategoryId=...`. If you get other new values in the `using` clause you can update with those, you just can't change the `on` column. (It sounds like you're duplicating data, which is a bit odd). If that doesn't help then you should ask a new question explaining your requirement and showing data and expected result.

Comment: Yes .. Duplicating the columns wasn't the right way to do it. Anyway, I changed the code.. I could solve the problem by not duplicating the two columns. Thank you so much for your help! Cheers :)

Comment: @KavitaSalvi If Alex' answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted (by clicking the checkmark button next to it).